# How to test performance of Oracle Forms Applications and Oracle ADF Application

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, oracleforms, oracle12c

I am new to either Oracle FORMS and Oracle ADF, but I will need to measure performance(get timings) of the same applications implemented in FORMS and in ADF.

-> I know that the technologies are different, which one is supposed to be faster, with a better user interface response?

-> Is ADF slower than FORMS because of the heavier interface?

-> What can be changed to increase performance on a ADF Application (Server?) ?

-> Are there any applications to perform benchmarking to the application?

I am asking this because I have already performed a quick run of both FORMS and ADF Application, and ADF is slower than FORMS.

Thank you so much,

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I know that the technologies are different, which one is supposed to be faster, with a better user interface response?

ADF can have great user interface response if used with performance in mind and utilizing Javascript inside your application.

### Is ADF slower than FORMS because of the heavier interface?

No, both behaves the same under the same circumstances, ADF can be enhanced when you apply performance procedures and ADF also provide great user experience to the user.

### What can be changed to increase performance on a ADF Application (Server?)

Consider reading [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/ASPER/adf.htm)

### Are there any applications to perform benchmarking to the application?

Use JMeter with ADF, see [a link for a demo](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adfjmeter/adfjmeter.html), and [another article](https://blogs.oracle.com/onesizedoesntfitall/entry/new_recording_on_using_jmeter) as well.